# Downloading a remote image gives error : stream.js:94 Error: ENOENT, open 'path/to/file'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download a remote image and save it in the images folder on my server.

I get the error `Error: ENOENT, open 'path/to/file'`

I use:

```
function download (uri, filename, callback) {
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    var r = request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
    r.on('close', callback);
  });
};

var imgURL = "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg"

var newImgName = "/images/imageName.jpg"
// If I do var newImgName = "imageName.jpg", it works.

download(imgURL, newImgName, function () {
  console.log('Done downloading..');
});
```

Comment: What's your project structure ? Does the folder images exists ?

Comment: it's an express app. The path is actually /public/images/ but public is set as a static folder like the css / javascripts folder. I also tried putting __dirname + infront of the newImgName param when calling download().

Comment: If you try to upload it at the root ?

Comment: At the root it worked! Saw done downloading..

Comment: @Dany : Make sure you have the folder 'images' in the root directory( if you intend for that) else put it as ZachRabbit explained and hv the folder reside in your projects root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a slash at the beginning of the `newImgName`, it's trying to put the image in the `images` folder in the root of your hard drive. If you're trying to put it in the `images` folder where your code is, try this:

```
var newImgName = "./images/imageName.jpg";
```

Comment: It gives the same `Error: ENOENT, open './images/y4e0PUB3GD.jpg'error. It actually should create that file from the original image file, right (not "opening" it like the error says)

Comment: Uploading it at the root worked (making newImgName = "imageName.jpg"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by creating the file from the original. Try throwing a `console.log(__dirname + '/images/')` in and making sure that the path displayed is the path you're wanting. It's possible you might have to go up a directory first (using `..` at the start of newImgName) or something of that variety.

Comment: When using __dirname, I do see "routesimages/images" instead of public/images

Comment: But I can't actually see routesimages in the structure, seems like express automatically use it in the back

Comment: Does something like `../public/images/` or `../../public/images/` work?

Comment: simply `public/images/` worked. Seems like routing isn't taken into account there. Thank you ;)